# How to check JSON Array value contains a list of numbers and return length

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a **MySQL** table  with the following definition:

```
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| numbers| json    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The table has some sample data as follows:

```
+----+------+----------------------------------+
| id | numbers                                 |
+----+------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | [1,2,3,4,5]                             |
|  2 | [2,3,7,8,9]                             |
|  3 | [5,7,10,15]                             |
+----+------+----------------------------------+
```

How can I calculate the total number of **matched numbers** (2,3,7,10) for each card? For example:

```
+----+---------+
| ID | Matches |
+----+---------+
| 1  | 2       |
| 2  | 3       |
| 3  | 2       | 
+----+---------+
```

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: If `numbers` is equal `[2,2]` then you need the result of `1` or `2`? Do not tell "the array cannot have duplicated values" - or prove this by table's CREATE TABLE with according CHECK constraint.

Comment: You can´t have duplicated numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 8+ you can cross join `json_table()` to get a row for each number ID combination (for the numbers in the JSON array of the ID). Then you can aggregate grouping by the ID and get the sum of instances where the number (from the JSON array) is in the list of numbers you search for.

```
SELECT t.id,
       sum(jt.number IN (2, 3, 7, 10)) matches
       FROM elbat t
            CROSS JOIN json_table(numbers, '$[*]' COLUMNS (number integer PATH '$')) jt
       GROUP BY t.id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=279acd52aee739ba098de40cf0353662)

Comment: If need to check same logic in two other columns how to write that SQL? Lets say columns: line1, line2, line3.

Comment: @JúlioPontes: That's another, new question you might want to ask.